Download SAM Exclusions List Using a Python script
I am attempting to write a Python script that will let me download the latest SAM Exclusions list from a government website.  I get very close, but when my Python script clicks on the link to download the file, a pop-up window appears and the user must scroll to the bottom of the pop-up box before the Accept button becomes active and you can click on it.  Once the Accept button is active and you click on it, the file will download.
Here is the website link to the SAM Exclusions file - https://sam.gov/data-services/Exclusions/Public%20V2?privacy=Public
When you put in this URL, you have to click on the OK button, select the very first Zip file link that is at the top, and then the other pop-up box appears where you have to scroll down in the box before the Accept button becomes active.
I am using a MacBook Pro and the MacOS to run my Python script.  Below is the Python script that I have developed so far.  Any assistance to allow the Python script to fully run and download the latest Exclusions file would be appreciated.
Here is my current script:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import os
import time

def download_latest_file():
try:
    print("Initializing Chrome WebDriver...")
    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    prefs = {'download.default_directory': '/Users/m_keiffer/Downloads'}  # Replace with     
    options.add_experimental_option('prefs', prefs)
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

    print("Opening the webpage...")
    driver.get("https://sam.gov/data-services/Exclusions/Public%20V2?privacy=Public")

    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)

    # Handle initial OK pop-up
    try:
        print("Handling initial OK pop-up...")
        ok_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
        ok_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        print("OK button clicked.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error handling initial OK pop-up: {str(e)}")

    # Find and click the correct download link
    try:
        print("Finding download links...")
        exclusions_link = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
        print(f"Clicking on the download link: {exclusions_link.text}")
        exclusions_link.click()
        time.sleep(5)
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error finding or clicking download link: {str(e)}")
        driver.quit()
        return

    # Handle Accept pop-up
    try:
        print("Handling Accept pop-up...")
        modal = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//sa-security-
        
        # Click inside the modal to activate it
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", modal)
        time.sleep(1)

        # Scroll to the bottom of the modal content
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollTop = arguments[0].scrollHeight", modal)
        time.sleep(2)  # Adjust time as necessary to ensure scroll is complete
        
        # Find and click the Accept button
        accept_button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", accept_button)
        print("Accept button clicked.")
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error handling Accept pop-up: {str(e)}")
        driver.quit()
        return

    # Wait for the download to complete
    time.sleep(20)

    download_path = "/Users/m_keiffer/Downloads"  # Replace with your actual username
    files_after = os.listdir(download_path)
    print(f"Files in Downloads: {files_after}")
    new_files = [f for f in files_after if f.endswith('.zip') or f.endswith('.csv')]
    if new_files:
        latest_file = max(new_files, key=lambda x:       
        print(f"Latest downloaded file: {latest_file}")
    else:
        print("No new files found in the Downloads folder.")

    driver.quit()
except Exception as e:
    print(f"Failed to initialize the WebDriver or other error: {str(e)}")

I have tried using ChatGPT to help me with the final step but so far nothing has worked.  I get to where the last pop-up box appears but I cannot get the Accept button to become active and to be selected.
This is the final step that I need to resolve - getting the Accept button on the last pop  up window to become active and then to be selected.  Once that happens, the file will download.  Again, here is the website I am going to - https://sam.gov/data-services/Exclusions/Public%20V2?privacy=Public
I am not sure if it is possible to do this in Python, so any help would be greatly appreciated!

What specifically is the "final step" that is at issue, and does you code include an attempt to solve it?

Hi Scott, the final step that I need to resolve is getting the Accept button on the pop-up window to become Active and selected.  I have tried some scrolling code in my script but that did not fix it.
